# Passing two models to a partial view asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass two models to a view. Now I have two models Messages and Comments. These are declared inside a ViewModel that I pass to the view. Till there everything works fine but I have created another model MergeModels that contains both Messages and Comments. This model is also declared in my ViewModel. But when I try to pass the MergeModels Model to the partial view it goes wrong and I get a error.

> Can type Portfolio.ViewModels.MessageViewModel model not convert implicitly into System.Collections.IEnumerable. There is an explicit conversion (is there a conversion?)

Also I now pass two full models to this partial view while I dont need all the data of both these models. Is there any way to pass only the data you need to the view/partialview?

I have looked arround on the internet but I was not able to get this working.

**Here are my Models**

```
namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Messages
    {
        public int MessagesId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public Messages()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Comments
    {
        public int CommentsId { get; set; }
        public string Comments_body { get; set; }
        public int Messages Messages {get; set;}
        public Messages MessagesId { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public Comments()
        {
             WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class MergeModel
    {
        public Messages Messages { get; set; }
        public Comments Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
namespace Portfolio.ViewModels
{
    public class MessageViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Messages> Messages { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MergeModel> MergeModel{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
namespace Portfolio.Controllers
{
    public class MessagesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MessagesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        public ActionResult Blog()
        {
            var viewModel = new MessageViewModel()
            {
            Messages = _context.messages.OrderByDescending(Messages => 
            Messages.WhenCreated),Comments = _context.comments

            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Comment()
        {
            var comment = _context.comments.ToList();

            return View(_context.comments.OrderByDescending(Comments => 
            Comments.WhenCreated));
        }
        public ActionResult Post()
       {
        return View();
        }

    //This binds the objects from the database to the values from the view

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues)
        {
            try
            {
                Messages message = new Messages();
                message.Title = formValues["Title"];
                message.Body = formValues["editor"];

                Comments comment = new Comments();
                comment.Comments_body = formValues["editor" + 
                message.MessagesId];

                _context.comments.Add(comment);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                _context.messages.Add(message);
                _context.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Blog");
        }
    }
}
```

**And here my view**

```
@model Portfolio.ViewModels.MessageViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blog";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/Comments.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                @foreach (var messages in Model.Messages)
                {
                    <div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
@*Gets the title of the blog post*@
                                 <h2 class="panel-title">
                                 @messages.Title</h2>@messages.WhenCreated
                                </div>
@*Gets the body of the blog post and decodes the html of the ckeditor*@
                                <div class="panel-body">
                 @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(messages.Body))
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
@*this button gets the id from the database of the Message table this helps 
to prevent that all the comments from all blogs gets shown and thus
shows only the comments that belong to the blog in question*@

                  <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                  id="@messages.MessagesId" onclick="ShowComments(this.id)">
                  Show Comments</button>

@*this is the container where al the comments are placed in and where you 
can post comments. The comments are placed in the Comment partial view*@

                        <div class="hidden" id="Comm@(messages.MessagesId)">
                            @Html.Partial("_Comment", Model.MergeModel)

@*this button gets the id from the database of the Message table this helps 
to prevent that all the comments from all blogs gets hidden and thus
hides only the comments that belong to the blog in question*@

                            <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                             id="@messages.MessagesId" 
                             onclick="HideComments(this.id)">
                             Hide Comments
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here my PartialView**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />

<div class="row" id="CommentContainer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Post Comment</h3>
@*The form to post comments*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Messages"))
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment</label>
            @Html.TextArea("editor", htmlAttributes: new { name = "editor1", 
            id = "editor", rows = "10", cols = "180" })
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
            id="PostButton">Post Comment</button>
        }

@*CKEdito script*@
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
    </script>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
@*Places al the comments and decodes the html from the ckeditor*@
                @foreach(var comments in Model)
                {
                    if (comments.CommentsId == messages.MessagesId)
                    {
                        <div class="well" id="CommentBox">
                        <h7>@comments.WhenCreated</h7>

        @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comments.Comments_body))
                    </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <h2>Be the first to react!</h2>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I am not realy sure how to call the model in this part

> @foreach(var comments in Model)

Because I pass in the view this to my partial view

> @Html.Partial("_Comment", Model.MergeModel)

So not only model I have tried different variations but it didnt work for example

> @foreach(var comments in Model.MergeModel)

**edit**
Because I was not clear enough,
 I am trying to show all the comments belonging to a message with the foreach statement. I had it working at first but it showed all the comments at all the messages instead of only showing the comments that belong to their message. This is why I need those two models in my partial view. I am trying to get the comments to show only at the message that it belongs to. This am I trying with the if statement where the id's need to be the same of the comment and the message

**edit**
Changed misstake in code,

```
if (comments.CommentsId == messages.MessagesId)
```

to

```
if (comments.MessagesId == messages.MessagesId)
```

and added

```
public Messages Messages{ get; set;}
```

in my Messages model

I am very new to both Asp.net mvc and stackoverflow so if there is any improvement in how to ask my question please let me know.

Comment: In your partial view I expected to see something like @model Portfolio.Models.MergeModel but model is not being declared. Why?

Comment: @derkloopkat shouldn't it be ```@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.Models.MergeModel>```

Comment: @derloopkat I thought that wasnt needed because I pass my model to my paritalview throug this line "@Html.Partial("_Comment", Model.MergeModel)"

Comment: Assuming the model of the partial view is a MergeModel, then it doesn't make sense when you do @foreach (var comments in Model). The model is an object, not a collection. So let's say we iterate over Model.Comments, then we have if (comments.CommentsId == messages.MessagesId), where messages is not defined.

Comment: @derloopkat allright thnx so what your saying is that i need to find a way to pass messages also to the variable in something like this @foreach(var comments in Model && var messages in Model)? I am still trying to get the hang of it all so please forgive me if this is a really stupid suggestion :p

Comment: @Hopeless yes, that's a good one. Even if you pass a MergeModel there are no collections to iterate across. Either the definition of MergeModel is incorrect or the call from the controller.

Comment: @ruinerwarrior There are fixes for the errors but they are correct or not depending on what you're trying to achieve and that point is not clear. As for naming convention, when you create a class, names should be in singular. For a collection, names are in plural. In your code "Comments" is a single comment, and "Messages" is a single message. It causes confusion as it looks like a collection. That "foreach" is trying to iterate through the elements of an object. Since it is not a collection but a single object, you get an error.

Comment: @derloopkat I am trying to show all the comments belonging to a message with the foreach statement. I had it working at first but it showed all the comments at all the messages instead of only showing the comments that belong to their message. This is why I need those two models in my partial view. I am trying to get the comments to show only at the message that it belongs to. This am I trying with the if statement where the id's need to be the same of the comment and the message

Comment: @ruinerwarrior In that case, your Message model needs to have a public List<Comment> Comments { get; set;} and that should be populated from Db for a specific message. Model classes need to be renamed as singular, same for Ids. You can use right click / refactor to prevent issues. My suggestion is make a back up of your project first.

Comment: @ruinerwarrior Please check out that code sample https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766214/List-Model-Binding-in-MVC It is similar to what you need and you can adapt the code by renaming classes. In the example an author can have many books. (1 Message --> N Comments) *(1 Author --> N Books)

Comment: @derloopkat thank you im going to look in to it!